# Equivalence of random effects via likelihood and smoothed splines

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, proof, generalized-additive-model

Some fake data:

```
X = runif(1000)
ff = rep(1:10,100)
E = rnorm(1000)
y = x+e+f
f = as.factor(ff)
```

When you fit a model like

```
library(mgcv)
m = gam(y~x+s(f,bs='re'),method='REML')
```

and

```
library(lme4)
mr = lmer(y~x+(1|f))
```

you are basically fitting the same model via different methods.  The former specifies the model like a least-squares dummy variable fixed-effects regression, then picks a smoothing parameter to "shrink" the intercept estimates.  The latter estimates the variance of the (assumed normally-distributed) variance of the effect of the factor.

Numerically, the two are roughly equivalent (but not exactly).  Running the following and letting it spin for a while shows (very) small differences, which increase and decrease at weird intervals, but generally seem to be decreasing in N.

```
d = c()
X = runif(10000)
ff = rep(1:10,1000)
E = rnorm(10000)
for (i in 20:10000){
    N=i
    x = X[1:N]
    f = ff[1:N]
    e = E[1:N]
    y = x+e+f
    f = as.factor(f)
    m = gam(y~x+s(f,bs='re'),method='REML')
    summary(m)
    library(lme4)
    mr = lmer(y~x+(1|f))
    d[i] = mean(abs(predict(m)-predict(mr)))
    plot(d)
    n = (1:N)
    if (N>20){abline(lm(d~n))}
    }
```

So my questions:

1. Under what conditions are the two methods exactly identical?  Is it only as $N$ or $n$ goes to infinity?  Where can I find a (hopefully well-explained) proof of any equivalence?
2. I'm guessing that those weird jumps I get when running that little simulation are artifacts of the various optimizers (or something) used in the software.  Is that more or less the case?

**EDIT:**
It turns out that this has been shown by Harville, 1976 and 1977.

Comment: It sounds like you could turn your edit into a brief answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generalized additve models (GAM) including smooth terms can be represented by generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) including random effects after appropriate reparameterization (see for proof, for example: [Fahrmeir/Kneib/Lang 2004: 742f.](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A14n36.pdf))
2. According to the author of the mgcv package the two models should be [equivalent](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/random.effects.html). Maybe you are picking up some artifact due to numerical precision of the different routines.